# Try it yourself or Try it for yourself

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

Which one is correct-
**Try it yourself** or
**Try it for yourself**.

If both are correct then please tell the scenario in which each should be used.

I am actually testing a website which contains one of those lines to Get Started with the site.

Comment: Why don't YOU tell US the scenario in which you wish to use it?

Comment: @TrevorD Because, er, s/he doesn't know what it means? And s/he's tried to explain the context that it what used in (though, not quite completely)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** *try it yourself* and *try it for yourself* basically mean the same thing, which is *You test it yourself.*

---

The meaning of [*try*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/try) in these sentences is

> to use, test, or do (something new or different) in order to see if it is suitable, effective, or pleasant

Now, Suppose I've prepared a dish. I offer it to you and you ask "*Does it taste good?*". In this situation I can reply with "*Try it yourself!*", meaning: *You test/taste it*. Simple.
I also can reply with *"Try it for yourself!"* with the same meaning, maybe a little bit more emphatic: *You should test it yourself* or *Why don't you taste it yourself?*
It's sort of an idiom, in which the preposition *for* shouldn't be taken literally.

Here are a couple examples from [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), where the contexts clearly show the meaning of *try it for yourself*:

> - In terms of deliberate strategies, both Teachers E and M advocated for the rule of **trying something on your own** before asking the teacher for help. Teacher E said, "*When they ask me for help I say,'Well you have to **try it for yourself** first'* ". Then from that, they will develop strategies as to how to go about solving a problem.
> - Those were reminiscences of just two days out of 75 we spent in Europe. That is what I am trying to say about bicycle touring. It is a magical mode of transportation. Wondrous things happen when you are touring by bike. If you don't believe me, **try it for yourself**.